# How can i select text from one document using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, text, selenium, highlight

Suppose i have one document then how can i *select text* from that document using `Selenium` `WebDriver`.

I have entered below code:

```
d1.findElementByClassName("odd").click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
d1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement el = d1.findElement(By.id("doc-content"));
Actions act = new Actions(d1);
act.clickAndHold(el).build().perform();
act.release().perform();
act.doubleClick(el).build().perform();
act.clickAndHold(el).build().perform();
WebElement el1 = d1.findElement(By.id("doc-data"));
act.moveToElement(el1, 50, 50).build().perform();
act.dragAndDropBy(el, 100, 150).build().perform();
act.release().build().perform();
```

Comment: In the title it says "select text" and in the body of the question it says "highlight". Selecting text and highlighting text are not necessarily the same operation. Is the code in your question supposed to do the selection? If yes, then how does it fail? Is something happening. Is nothing happening? Is it crashing? Causing an error message? Moreover, sometimes the issue is whether or not native events are used. Native event support changes depending on which version of Selenium you are using, and which browser and version of browser is used. So what are they?

Comment: Above code will be select blank space in my browser. And i use Chrome Browser Version 32.0.1700.102. and selenium version is 2.39.0.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to Highlight found element, you can try to run js to change style for that element:

```
WebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id('someId'));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor='yellow';", element);
```

Or change font color:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.color='yellow';", element);
```

Comment: arguments[0] <- value that you pass in, in example is "element"

Comment: you have any example?Can you elaborate?

Comment: In answer first example, you found WebElement (element) then you pass it to executeScript and using it through arguments[0], where arguments[0] is element you pass in executeScript